# ReactNative: using Atom IDE

Tags: android, react-native, atom-editor

I'm trying to code for [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) in Atom but it is very inconvenient because I have to type each single word. How to set up Atom for auto-complete and auto-import just like Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Atom can do that as perfect as Android Studio. It's an editor, not an IDE. At this time, there is no easy way to get perfect auto-complete support for Android on Atom.

Comment: is there any other way??

Answer (score 6):

Atom is super cool Ide for building react-native application.there are alot of pakages for atom for developing RN apps like [atom-react-native-autocomplete](https://github.com/DavidWells/atom-react-autocomplete)

[image]

Facebook developed [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) package for Atom. Which provide first-class developing environment for react-native.